# Grails: Simple hasMany relation create more tables than necessary

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi I have a simple problem.
My domain class is like this:

```
class Example {

    long seq

    hasMany = [example_array: ExampleData]

    long count
}

class ExampleData {

    String type

    long description

    static belongsTo = Example

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

This results in 3 tables, like a many to many relation.
Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the extra table is that you've modeled the relation only in one direction - an `Example` can access its `ExampleData` instances via the `example_array` Set that's added to your class bytecode because of the `hasMany` property, but an `ExampleData` instance has no way to reference its owning `Example`.

You added a `belongsTo` property, but only specified the class name. That's sufficient to configure ownership, cascaded deletes, etc. but doesn't provide a property in the class to access the `Example` instance.

If you change it to the other supported syntax it will work as you expected:

```
static belongsTo = [example: Example]
```

Here `example` will end up being the name of an `Example` property (and you can change it and/or `example_array` to any valid property name), which is basically the same as declaring

```
Example example
```

Now that both sides can access the other, the relationship is bidirectional and you no longer need the third table. That's because a 1-many is typically implemented using a foreign key in the child table, in this case in the table for `ExampleData` that points to the table for `Example`. That wasn't possible without a property in the class to wire up to that column, so the join table was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to map the BelongsTo, like this:

```
static belongsTo = [example:Example]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No, you don't have to assign a `Map` to `belongsTo`.  You can assign a `Map` or a `Class`.  If you use a `Map` then a back reference is added in the class that defines the `belongsTo`.  If you use a `Class`, that doesn't happen.  See http://docs.grails.org/3.1.11/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html.

Comment: If you use a `Map`, the schema will be different, and that may be what you want, but it isn't the case that you have to use a `Map`.

Comment: Ok, but he wants to get rid off the third table, this will do it. Burt Beckwith explained with good words.

Comment: I didn't know he wanted to get rid of it.  I thought he wanted to know why it was there. "This results in 3 tables, like a many to many relation. Why is this?"

Comment: I guess you are right, I might have assumed wrong. Either way, it does not look like he was looking for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of hasMany Grails will, by default, map this kind of relationship with a join table.That join table is the 3rd table you mentioned.No need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well the `one-to-many relationship` is constructed by having additional table (i.e. `Example_ExampleData`) containing two columns each `id` fields from tables of the entities forming the relationship(i.e. `Example` and `ExampleData`).

The newly added table is child to parent tables – `Example` and `ExampleData`.

So in your case when you run your application the 3rd table gets created by `Grails` by default as your table relationship falls under the `one-to-many relationship`.